# Flutter - NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

This is a flutter program to get the list of videos in a YouTube PlayList. I am facing a weird issue that happens only when I substitute a String variable from literal string to a parameter that is a String.

I have the following code:

```
class ChosenSubject extends StatefulWidget {
  final Subject subject;
  ChosenSubject({Key? key, required this.subject}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChosenSubject> createState() => _ChosenSubjectState();
}

class _ChosenSubjectState extends State<ChosenSubject> {
  late Playlist _playlist;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _playlist = Playlist();
    _playlist.items = List.empty(growable: true);
    _loadPlaylist();
  }

  _loadPlaylist() async {
    //String playlistId = 'PLSBMQBvBnLEOYH-gxMHCcdmA4liLhK-F8';
    String playlistId = widget.subject.playlistId; // this returns the string 'PLSBMQBvBnLEOYH-gxMHCcdmA4liLhK-F8'. Verified it.
    print(playlistId);
    Playlist playlist = await Services.getPlaylist(playlistId: playlistId); // This call errors
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.subject.name),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The services.dart file is:

```
class Services {
  static const _baseUrl = 'youtube.googleapis.com';

  static Future<Playlist> getPlaylist({required String playlistId}) async {
    Map<String, String> parameters = {
      'part': 'snippet',
      'playlistId': playlistId,
      'maxResults': '25',
      'key': Constants.API_KEY,
    };
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
    };
    Uri uri = Uri.https(
      _baseUrl,
      'youtube/v3/playlistItems',
      parameters,
    );
    http.Response response = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);
    Playlist playlistItem = playlistFromJson(response.body);
    return playlistItem;
  }
}
```

The playlist.dart file

```
import 'dart:convert';

Playlist playlistFromJson(String str) => Playlist.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String playlistToJson(Playlist data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Playlist {
  Playlist({
    this.kind,
    this.etag,
    this.items,
    this.pageInfo,
  });

  String? kind;
  String? etag;
  List<Item>? items;
  PageInfo? pageInfo;

  factory Playlist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Playlist(
        kind: json["kind"],
        etag: json["etag"],
        items: List<Item>.from(json["items"].map((x) => Item.fromJson(x))),
        pageInfo: PageInfo.fromJson(json["pageInfo"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "kind": kind,
        "etag": etag,
        "items": List<dynamic>.from(items!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "pageInfo": pageInfo?.toJson(),
      };
}

class Item {
  Item({
    required this.kind,
    required this.etag,
    required this.id,
    required this.snippet,
  });

  String kind;
  String etag;
  String id;
  Snippet snippet;

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
        kind: json["kind"],
        etag: json["etag"],
        id: json["id"],
        snippet: Snippet.fromJson(json["snippet"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "kind": kind,
        "etag": etag,
        "id": id,
        "snippet": snippet.toJson(),
      };
}

class Snippet {
  Snippet({
    required this.publishedAt,
    required this.channelId,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.thumbnails,
    required this.channelTitle,
    required this.playlistId,
    required this.position,
    required this.resourceId,
    required this.videoOwnerChannelTitle,
    required this.videoOwnerChannelId,
  });

  DateTime publishedAt;
  String channelId;
  String title;
  String description;
  Thumbnails thumbnails;
  String channelTitle;
  String playlistId;
  int position;
  ResourceId resourceId;
  String videoOwnerChannelTitle;
  String videoOwnerChannelId;

  factory Snippet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Snippet(
        publishedAt: DateTime.parse(json["publishedAt"]),
        channelId: json["channelId"],
        title: json["title"],
        description: json["description"],
        thumbnails: Thumbnails.fromJson(json["thumbnails"]),
        channelTitle: json["channelTitle"],
        playlistId: json["playlistId"],
        position: json["position"],
        resourceId: ResourceId.fromJson(json["resourceId"]),
        videoOwnerChannelTitle: json["videoOwnerChannelTitle"],
        videoOwnerChannelId: json["videoOwnerChannelId"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "publishedAt": publishedAt.toIso8601String(),
        "channelId": channelId,
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
        "thumbnails": thumbnails.toJson(),
        "channelTitle": channelTitle,
        "playlistId": playlistId,
        "position": position,
        "resourceId": resourceId.toJson(),
        "videoOwnerChannelTitle": videoOwnerChannelTitle,
        "videoOwnerChannelId": videoOwnerChannelId,
      };
}

class ResourceId {
  ResourceId({
    required this.kind,
    required this.videoId,
  });

  String kind;
  String videoId;

  factory ResourceId.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResourceId(
        kind: json["kind"],
        videoId: json["videoId"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "kind": kind,
        "videoId": videoId,
      };
}

class Thumbnails {
  Thumbnails({
    required this.thumbnailsDefault,
    required this.medium,
    required this.high,
    required this.standard,
  });

  Default thumbnailsDefault;
  Default medium;
  Default high;
  Default standard;

  factory Thumbnails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Thumbnails(
        thumbnailsDefault: Default.fromJson(json["default"]),
        medium: Default.fromJson(json["medium"]),
        high: Default.fromJson(json["high"]),
        standard: Default.fromJson(json["standard"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "default": thumbnailsDefault.toJson(),
        "medium": medium.toJson(),
        "high": high.toJson(),
        "standard": standard.toJson(),
      };
}

class Default {
  Default({
    required this.url,
    required this.width,
    required this.height,
  });

  String url;
  int width;
  int height;

  factory Default.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Default(
        url: json["url"],
        width: json["width"],
        height: json["height"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "url": url,
        "width": width,
        "height": height,
      };
}

class PageInfo {
  PageInfo({
    required this.totalResults,
    required this.resultsPerPage,
  });

  int totalResults;
  int resultsPerPage;

  factory PageInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PageInfo(
        totalResults: json["totalResults"],
        resultsPerPage: json["resultsPerPage"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "totalResults": totalResults,
        "resultsPerPage": resultsPerPage,
      };
}
```

When I run the program, the following call works fine:

```
String playlistId = 'PLSBMQBvBnLEOYH-gxMHCcdmA4liLhK-F8';
Playlist playlist = await Services.getPlaylist(playlistId: playlistId);
```

But when I substitute playListId string with:

```
String playlistId = widget.subject.playlistId;
Playlist playlist = await Services.getPlaylist(playlistId: playlistId);
```

I get the "NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null" error.

```
E/flutter ( 8015): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 8015): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 8015): Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Item)
E/flutter ( 8015): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
E/flutter ( 8015): #1      new Playlist.fromJson
E/flutter ( 8015): #2      playlistFromJson
E/flutter ( 8015): #3      Services.getPlaylist
E/flutter ( 8015): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8015): #4      _ChosenSubjectState._loadPlaylist
E/flutter ( 8015): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8015):
Restarted application in 912ms.
Reloaded 1 of 1102 libraries in 279ms.
Reloaded 1 of 1102 libraries in 229ms.
```

`String playlistId = widget.subject.playlistId;` returns the same string 'PLSBMQBvBnLEOYH-gxMHCcdmA4liLhK-F8'. Verified it by logging on the console.

Can someone help me with this?

Edit:
The API call result:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": "F9DlUsG8_KHE4LmXUFhEuInW02c",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
      "etag": "jvRF3UDOSJ3jOpT9yF0HK4cJYoM",
      "id": "UExTQk1RQnZCbkxFTnJVN3lPOVRNRVFBUzJrQ1k5UEdzWS41NkI0NEY2RDEwNTU3Q0M2",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2022-06-30T09:21:42Z",
        "channelId": "UCB3igi7VFgReyXmnvS3EZ4A",
        "title": "Mathematics-1",
        "description": "",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vCwOjckCe30/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vCwOjckCe30/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vCwOjckCe30/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "standard": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vCwOjckCe30/sddefault.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480
          },
          "maxres": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vCwOjckCe30/maxresdefault.jpg",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "SARP CRT",
        "playlistId": "PLSBMQBvBnLENrU7yO9TMEQAS2kCY9PGsY",
        "position": 0,
        "resourceId": {
          "kind": "youtube#video",
          "videoId": "vCwOjckCe30"
        },
        "videoOwnerChannelTitle": "SARP CRT",
        "videoOwnerChannelId": "UCB3igi7VFgReyXmnvS3EZ4A"
      }
    }
  ],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the response if it is returning the proper data?

This error seems to be getting called in the `playlistFromJson()` method when it's trying to map the items.

Your error most likely may be here:
```items: List<Item>.from(json["items"].map((x) => Item.fromJson(x))),```

Comment: Can you post the sample json that you will get from the api call.

Comment: @Stefano Alvares - I understand the error is in playlistFromJson. But only when I use this code String playlistId = widget.subject.playlistId;. When I assign the string 'PLSBMQBvBnLEOYH-gxMHCcdmA4liLhK-F8' directly to playlistId it works fine. I printed out `value of ``widget.subject.playlistId``` and it is'PLSBMQBvBnLEOYH-gxMHCcdmA4liLhK-F8'

Comment: @Sagar Acharya - I have added it to the question.

Comment: Code seems to be fine and working, what i think is you can check again all of the following 1) Both the id are same 2) the response that you are getting just compare both of them if there is any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue. The API was returning an error when `widget.subject.playlistId` was passed. When Uri was constructed, it was adding an extra '+' character to the string in  `widget.subject.playlistId` . So the API returned error and the program crashed.

Parsed the '+' out it works now.

Thanks @Sagar Acharya your suggestions helped me in finding a solution.